# How to populate a field in Unix

Tags: unix, grep, formatting, awk

I have file with two fileds as below and i need to populate values in field 1 based on first value in a line as in output.

**INPUT:**

```
USA 3Q  2013
    4Q  2013
    1Q  2014
    2Q  2014
    3Q  2014
    4Q  2014
    1Q  2015
    2Q  2015
    3Q  2015
BRAZIL  3Q  2013
    4Q  2013
    1Q  2014
    2Q  2014
    3Q  2014
    4Q  2014
    1Q  2015
    2Q  2015
    3Q  2015
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
USA 3Q  2013
USA 4Q  2013
USA 1Q  2014
USA 2Q  2014
USA 3Q  2014
USA 4Q  2014
USA 1Q  2015
USA 2Q  2015
USA 3Q  2015
BRAZIL  3Q  2013
BRAZIL  4Q  2013
BRAZIL  1Q  2014
BRAZIL  2Q  2014
BRAZIL  3Q  2014
BRAZIL  4Q  2014
BRAZIL  1Q  2015
BRAZIL  2Q  2015
BRAZIL  3Q  2015
```

Answer (score 2):

Another awk way

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 'NF!=3{$0=x$0}{x=$1=$1}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can for example use this:

```
$ awk 'NF==3 {a=$1; print; next} {print a, $0}' file | column -t
USA     3Q  2013
USA     4Q  2013
USA     1Q  2014
USA     2Q  2014
USA     3Q  2014
USA     4Q  2014
USA     1Q  2015
USA     2Q  2015
USA     3Q  2015
BRAZIL  3Q  2013
BRAZIL  4Q  2013
BRAZIL  1Q  2014
BRAZIL  2Q  2014
BRAZIL  3Q  2014
BRAZIL  4Q  2014
BRAZIL  1Q  2015
BRAZIL  2Q  2015
BRAZIL  3Q  2015
```

It catches the first field in case there are 3 of them. Then, it uses it together with the rest of the line.

Finally, `column -t` formats the output in tab-separated columns

Comment: Shortened awk `awk 'NF!=3{$0=x$0}x=$1'` or `awk 'NF!=3{$0=x$0}{x=$1}1'` incase first field is 0(unlikely in this case)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NF<3{$0=k $0} {k=$1} 1' file
```

or if you care about preserving the white space with GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,k); k=gensub(/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+).*/,"\\1","")} 1' file
USA 3Q  2013
USA 4Q  2013
USA 1Q  2014
USA 2Q  2014
USA 3Q  2014
USA 4Q  2014
USA 1Q  2015
USA 2Q  2015
USA 3Q  2015
BRAZIL  3Q  2013
BRAZIL  4Q  2013
BRAZIL  1Q  2014
BRAZIL  2Q  2014
BRAZIL  3Q  2014
BRAZIL  4Q  2014
BRAZIL  1Q  2015
BRAZIL  2Q  2015
BRAZIL  3Q  2015
```

With other awks that'd be:

```
$ awk '{sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,k); match($0,/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/); k=substr($0,1,RLENGTH)} 1' file
```